# CLion - SDL Libraries not found Mac

Tags: c, macos, sdl-2, clion

I have recently started programming on Clion, and I would like to create a Snake game in C language. I have downloaded all the necessary SDL libraries via Homebrew, and I have copied these files into my **Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/** folder. My C compiler is in this folder.
I have tried using **CMakeLists.txt** but I cannot get it to work properly.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(test)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

INCLUDE(FindPkgConfig)

pkg_check_modules(SDL2 REQUIRED sdl2)
pkg_check_modules(SDL2_IMG REQUIRED sdl2_image)
pkg_check_modules(SDL2_TTF REQUIRED sdl2_ttf)
pkg_check_modules(SDL2_MIXER REQUIRED sdl2_mixer)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_IMG REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_TTF REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_MIXER REQUIRED)

add_executable(test ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.c)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/assets)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        ${SDL2_IMG_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        ${SDL2_TTF_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        ${SDL2_MIXER_INCLUDE_DIRS})

link_directories(${SDL2_LIBRARY_DIRS}
        ${SDL2_IMG_LIBRARY_DIRS}
        ${SDL2_TTF_LIBRARY_DIRS}
        ${SDL2_MIXER_LIBRARY_DIRS})

target_link_libraries (test
        ${SDL2_LIBRARIES}
        ${SDL2_IMG_LIBRARIES}
        ${SDL2_TTF_LIBRARIES}
        ${SDL2_MIXER_LIBRARIES})
```

I have looked through many similar questions here on stackoverflow but none of them seemed to solve my issue.
If I include the `find_package`, I get this error message:
`Could not find a package configuration file SDL2_IMG` and so on. If I leave it out I get this `library not found for -lSDL2_image`.

Answer (score 0):

1. sdl2 libraries should download individually. mixer, ttf, etc
2. I worked with SDL2 on XCode without problem (easy)
3. Rather then compiler location, I prefer project location.
4. By the way, I indicate header files as path

I wish these help you.

Comment: Sadly, I am not able to download XCode because it takes too much space and it does not let me download it, even though I have around 35gb free space. I have downloaded the SDL2 Libraries individually through homebrew. What do you mean by 'Rather then compiler location, you prefer project location'?